# Geomtry Nodes Brick Wall on Curve Gap Keeps Moving

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I want to build a brick wall on a curve but with my current setup whenever I pull on the curve the gap in between the bricks grows and shrinks depending on how many bricks it adds. I can't have a gap in between the bricks because I'm planning on using this for a certain type of tile. Is there a way to put a row of bricks on a curve where I can move the curve without affecting the spacing of the bricks? It's important that it's in geometry nodes because I want to be able to customize the rotation and have a one click solution for making tiles.  [image]

[image: Bricks before pulling on curve]

[image: Bricks after pulling on curve]